# Why is my OnClick Method on the Button not working?

Tags: android, onclick, viewmodel, android-databinding

I am trying to call Methods via DataBinding from the ViewModel. I have tried changing the code inside the layout file for onClick, but nothing works. It shows this error:

Listener class android.view.View.OnClickListener with method onClick did not match signature of any method model::click

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.example.myapplication.MainActivityViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:text="Hey I am a Text View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Press Me"
            android:onClick="@{model::click}"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    MainActivityViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
        binding.setModel(viewModel);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public void click(){
        Log.d(TAG, "click: This Button got Clicked");
    }
}
```

I want a Log Message, when the Button is clicked

Answer (score 3):

You need a `View` object parameter in your onclick fundtion:

```
    public void click(View view){
        Log.d(TAG, "click: This Button got Clicked");
    }
```

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#HandlingEvents), your function must meet following requirements:

> Be public
>   Return void
>   Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

This parameter is important because you can set this function to listen to multiple views instead of creating a separate function for every view. Then you can compare this object with your views to check which one was clicked.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more question. How can I set the Text of the TextView through the onClick function?

Comment: You can make an interface and have your Activity implement it, ViewModel will keep an instance of the interface. MainActivity will set the instance by calling viewmodel.setActionListener(this). (assuming the interface name was ActionListener)

Now your viewmodel can call a function in your Activity without knowing that it is your activity.

Comment: @Riva you will change the text in the Overriden function in MainActivity. I hope above comment made sense, if it didn't then please do took a look at interfaces

Comment: Also, please follow above answer from @Tidder instead, it is more suited for databinding since mine is for without databinding

Answer (score 1):

Define your click handler like so:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:text="Press Me"
android:onClick="@{() -> model.click()}"/>
```

Comment: I failed to notice the databinding, nice one

Comment: Thanks to both of you <3